MSK Connector log level update
I am using the Kafka Snowflake connector as the MSK Connector. Default setting of the log level for logs is INFO, I could not find a way to change that.
Does the AWS MSK Connect API / CLI allow this to be changed?

You cannot change log level for MSK connect connectors. It's always INFO level

Does that mean that MSK does not support the Kafka Connector API? There does seem to be an AWS API for managing MSK connector may be it is not fully compliant?

MSK Connect is a fully managed service to run Kafka Connectors. This indeed means that it doesn't expose Connect APIs. Instead, MSK Connect makes sure the tasks are running, it reports metrics to CloudWatch, and exposes log output based on configuration. AWS does provide API for MSK Connect management: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/MSKC/latest/mskc/Welcome.html
